# Data values with /summon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wish to summon a wet sponge in front of me. I know:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:sponge,Count:1}
```

But I don't know how to add wet sponge's data value (1) in that command.

There seems to be a lack of online information on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item's data value is stored as the `Damage` tag:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:sponge",Count:1,Damage:1}}
```

The wiki has a list of all item NBT data [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the wet sponge is a different block, so it works with another name ID. Using `minecraft:wet_sponge` ought to work.